# AngularJS - Adding shortcut to object in the scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my highest level scope, I fetch some data from the server for use throughout the page like this: `$scope.lotsOfData = $http.get("lotsOfData");`. So now my scope holds a promise object for `lotsOfData`. Then, in my HTML, I have directives that are only concerned with a small set of the `lotsOfData` object. One such directive could look something like this:

```
<div>
    {{lotsOfData.foo.blah[source].bar[id].someData}}<br>
    {{lotsOfData.foo.blah[source].bar[id].otherData}}<br>
    {{lotsOfData.foo.blah[source].bar[id].differentData}}
</div>
```

where source and id are being set through attributes on the directive. My HTML page then looks something like this:

```
<data-subset source="1" id="1" />
<data-subset source="1" id="2" />
<data-subset source="2" id="1" />
<data-subset source="3" id="1" />
```

I hate having to repeat `lotsOfData.foo.blah[source].bar[id]` throughout the directive. Is there any way to set in the scope so my directive could look more like this?

```
<div>
    {{currObj.someData}}<br>
    {{currObj.otherData}}<br>
    {{currObj.differentData}}
</div>
```

Not only does this clean up the HTML, but if we ever restructure that `lotsOfData` object, there's be only one place to change how it's getting the `currObj` object. In the link function for my directive I tried this:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.currObj = scope.lotsOfData.foo.blah[attrs.source].bar[attrs.id];
}
```

However, since `lotsOfData` is a promise object, it doesn't have a property called `foo`. I don't know a whole lot about how the promise object works, so maybe I just need to know how I can get to the properties I need.

I hope what I'm trying to accomplish here makes sense and someone could point me in the right direction as to how to make this work. Thanks.

Comment: You can get your scope based example to work using a plain old controller, a directive is overkill for that...  like this: `<div ng-controller="data-subset" source="1" id="1"> {{curObj().someData ... </div>` and then in your js, make a controller: `myModule.controller('dataSsubset',function($scope, $attrs) {
  $scope.currObj = (function(){ return $scope.lotsOfData && $scope.lotsOfData.foo.blah[attrs.source].bar[attrs.id]; });
});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I accomplished what I wanted to. I created an outer directive to the one mentioned above and then created an isolated scope for the inner directive that bound to the data I wanted.

So my outer directive HTML looks like this:

```
<div>
    <data-subset curr-obj="lotsOfData.foo.blah[source].bar[id]"></data-subset>
</div>
```

And the javascript looks like this:

```
myModule.directive('outer-data', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            templateUrl: 'outerData.html',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.id = attrs.id;
                scope.source = attrs.source;
            },
            scope: true
        }
    });
```

Then the javscript for my dataSubset looks like this:

```
myModule.directive('dataSubset', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            templateUrl: 'dataSubset.htm',
            scope: {
                currObj: '='
            }
        }
    });
```

So then in my top-level HTML file I have something like this:

```
<outer-data source="1" id="1" />
<outer-data source="1" id="2" />
<outer-data source="2" id="1" />
<outer-data source="3" id="1" />
```

And I can just reference currObj on my dataSubset like I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$watch('lotsOfData.foo.blah['+attrs.source+'].bar['+attrs.id+']', function(newVal, oldVal) {
        scope.currObj = newVal;
    }
}
```

This should fix the problem, you will simply watch for changes on your data and set the `currObj` with the new value.

Comment: I didn't take the time to see if this worked for what I wanted as I came up with my own solution that I prefer. Thanks for the info though.